# Launching Rstudio AMI from snapshot fails

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a snapshot of a previous volume that I was running Rstudio from on AWS.
I would like to start a new instance using this snapshot but I cant seem to get it to work.

These are the steps I have taken.

1. Started the configuration for a new instance using [ami-0e9e5245fffe34a3e](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=eu-west-2#launchAmi=ami-0e9e5245fffe34a3e) which is from the website http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/
2. On the page to Add storage (step 4) I added a new volume using the snapshot ID. The device name I registered as /dev/sdf/

I then launched the instance and waited for it to Initialize. And then when I put in the IP...Nothing comes up.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**

So I ran the system error logs and this is what I get.

```
[   13.609760] cloud-init[484]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   13.620156] cloud-init[484]: Original exception was:
[   13.632215] cloud-init[484]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   13.638802] cloud-init[484]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   13.650278] cloud-init[484]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   13.657442] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 9, in <module>
[   13.664520] cloud-init[484]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==18.3', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   13.672141] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 882, in main
[   13.684552] cloud-init[484]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   13.696289] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2482, in log_time
[   13.709879] cloud-init[484]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   13.716287] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 673, in status_wrapper
[   13.724810] cloud-init[484]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[   13.736874] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[   13.761530] cloud-init[484]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   13.772280] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   13.795084] cloud-init[484]:     raise e
[   13.801381] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[   13.809589] cloud-init[484]:     tf.close()
[   13.814457] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 648, in close
[   13.822598] cloud-init[484]:     self._closer.close()
[   13.829168] cloud-init[484]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 582, in close
[   13.836968] cloud-init[484]:     self.file.close()
[   13.843478] cloud-init[484]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

I think the problem is some python file I left hanging around on the volume. There are a few files on the snapshot that I really need to get. Is there a way of getting them despite the fact that I have a no space left of device error. Or how do I increase the amount of space and hopefully make this retrievable?

Thi

Comment: Is the instance running? Do you see any errors in the system log?

Comment: Hi @RodrigoM Im sure the instance is running as per the AWS console. But how do I check the system logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turned out i needed to allow the security group for my instance to allow TCP on port 80. Its always the simple things...